# How to set env variable to the specific value out of multiple output values of some command?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm using following command to find out the pid for some string e.g. myname.

`for /f "TOKENS=1" %a in ('wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%myname%' and  name ='java.exe'" get processid')  do set myid=%a`

This command returns me below o/p.

`set myid=ProcessId 
 set myid=1928 
 set myid=`

In the end it sets empty value to myid. How can i set the process id which is 1928?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "TOKENS=* delims=" %a in ('wmic PROCESS where "commandline '%myname%' and  name ='java.exe'" get processid /format:value')  do (set "%a" >nul)
set proc
```

try like this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. it does not work for me. Seeing some issue in command itself.

Comment: @Karn - fixed.Forgot to set tokens and delims.Mind the format

Comment: Still seeing the issue as listed below.
mynamevalue') was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Thanks it fix my issue. Earlier I was trying in batch file so thats why having some difficulty

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if I put it into a bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "TOKENS=1 skip=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "commandline '%myname%' and  name ='java.exe'" get processid') do (
    SET PID=%%a
    GOTO BREAK
)
:BREAK
ECHO %PID%
```

The important data is stored in the 2nd output so just skip the first and exit the FOR-loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
i tried but PID still show blank value. 
Added **like** between  **commandline**  and **'%myname%'**